# QEMU Aarch64 and networking connections

Tags: arm, qemu

I just set up an ARM64 image using QEMU and I'm trying to access the internet from within the binary. The host OS(Ubuntu) receives internet from the `eth0` interface. I have the `tap0` interface set up. I've added `tap0` and `eth0` to `virbr0`.

```
$ brctl show virbr0
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
virbr0      8000.080027c9997e   yes     eth0
                                        tap0
```

Now, I try to start the VM as follows :-

```
sudo qemu-system-aarch64 -machine virt -cpu cortex-a57 -nographic -smp 1 -m 512 \
    -global virtio-blk-device.scsi=off -device virtio-scsi-device,id=scsi \
    -drive file=ubuntu-core-14.04.1-core-arm64.img,id=coreimg,cache=unsafe,if=none -device scsi-hd,drive=coreimg \
    -kernel vmlinuz-3.13.0-55-generic \
    -initrd initrd.img-3.13.0-55-generic \
    -netdev user,id=unet -device virtio-net-device,netdev=unet \
    -net nic -net tap,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no \
    --append "console=ttyAMA0 root=/dev/sda"
```

The output of ifconfig on host is as follows :-

```
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:c9:99:7e
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fec9:997e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2942 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7889 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:239227 (239.2 KB)  TX bytes:557156 (557.1 KB)

tap0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 8e:3d:c3:0e:58:36
          inet6 addr: fe80::8c3d:c3ff:fe0e:5836/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:412 errors:0 dropped:427 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:21432 (21.4 KB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:c9:99:7e
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2928 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2940 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:195163 (195.1 KB)  TX bytes:236587 (236.5 KB)
```

Once I start the VM, the output of ifconfig is as follows.

```
root@localhost:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:12:34:57
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:fe12:3457/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:38 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:846 (846.0 B)  TX bytes:3320 (3.3 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

However, I don't seem to be able to ping any remote addresses(eg: 8.8.8.8). Why does this happen? How can I fix this?

[EDIT]
When starting the VM I get the following warnings.

```
W: /etc/qemu-ifup: no bridge for guest interface found
Warning: hub port hub0port0 has no peer
Warning: vlan 0 with no nics
Warning: netdev hub0port0 has no peer
Warning: requested NIC (anonymous, model unspecified) was not created (not supported by this machine?)
```

Comment: Your `virbr0` uses `10.0.2.25` as an address, that is private. So what's your route to `8.8.8.8`?

Comment: @ikrabbe Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. I have not added in any routes using iptables.

Comment: When you have an interface on your host with an address `10.0.2.25` and nothing else, how is this private IP routed to access the internet? Show us your `ip route` on the host, would be a first approach. It also seems that your virtual host through tap0 has the same address as the `virbr0`. How do you ping from the host to the client and vice versa?

Comment: You need `-net nic -net tap,ifname=tap0` not `-net user`. You'd use the `user` stuff if you were *not* configuring your own bridge.

Comment: @mikeserv I'm not using "-net user". I've tried using both "-netdev user" and "-netdev tap". Is that what you meant?

Comment: Oh I see - why are you doing two? Just do one.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting same warnings while I used the obsolete `-net` option.  Then I changed it to this:

```
-netdev tap,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no,id=my_net_id \
-device driver=virtio-net,netdev=my_net_id
```

It fixed the problem.